# How to find and install specify package by command?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, repository

As far as I know, Linux can only install package from its Repository list.

And there are plenty of repositories out there.

After you have installed/updated the repository list, you can install the package you want.

But... I have no idea how to find a repository list that has the specified version of a package I want to install.

For example, I want to install php55u, not php55w or whatever.

Where/how can I find such a repository list or whatever that contains the php55u so I can have yum install it?

Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using CentOS because of the tag I can say this:

Additional packages are often in 3rd party repos. Information on additional CentOS repos is available at http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories Pay attention to the reference on yum-priorities.

Answer (score 0):

According to [these](https://centoshelp.org/servers/web/installing-php-5-5x-or-5-6x-on-centos/) official CentOS instructions about the package you are looking for, it most likely isn't available for CentOS 7.

If however you are on CentOS 6, you can

a) query for `php55u` - related packages:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=ius list php55u*
```

b) install `php55u`

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=ius install php55u
```